# Android: How can I include a Notification Sound using a Sound Resource?

Tags: android, resources, audio, notifications

Looking at the developer documentation, I see [how to use the default sound and how to use a Uri](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Sound), but I don't see how to use a resource. How can I use one of the sounds in my `res/raw` folder? Such as an MP3 or WAV file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://[package]/[res id]");
```

Example:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage/"+R.raw.mysound_1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);
```

Add to notification builder

```
.setSound(soundUri)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were probably looking for:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.your_sound);
```